# Render to common canvas with Polymer elements

Tags: javascript, canvas, polymer

What would be the best way to allow multiple Polymer elements access to a common canvas?

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<my-element canvas="myCanvas"></my-element>
```

Inside `my-element` is does `document.getElementById({{myCanvas}}` and then starts drawing to it.

Is this the best way or is there a better MDV type way?

The problem I see with this is that web components are encapsulated so that the identification string will be invalid between encapsulate components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that if `<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>` is in another shadow dom subtree, `document.getElementById('myCanvas')` wont' find it. Instead, you could use `document.querySelector('body /deep/ #myCanvas')`, but that's brittle and only finds the first `#myCanvas` anywhere in a shadow tree.

A better approach would be to set the `.canvas` property on the outside:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<my-element></my-element>

document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
  document.querySelector('my-element').canvas = document.querySelector('#myCanvas');
});
```

The other thing we typically do is wrap elements together inside another `<polymer-element>`. This woudld allow you to data-bind the canvas DOM element to my-element's `canvas` published property (attribute):

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<my-element canvas="{{$.myCanvas}}"></my-element>
```

Comment: I was just sat at home thinking, i wonder if i could bind to `$.myCanvas`...seems you've confirmed this! Thanks for all your work with the web components/polymer dev relations.

Comment: I never thought to bind directly to the $ property! That should be a "pro tip" or something in the docs if it's not already :)